# How many pageviews can my server handle per day?

Tags: server, mysql, load

I'm sharing some space on a dedicated server, but I'm not sure of the exact specifications. It is very fast though, and the person who I'm sharing the server with say they spend about 1400 a month on it and they are the same servers used by the defense department. There site is a small business site that maybe has 150 pages views per day.

My site has none at the moment but I was wondering how many it could take. My site is simple, and runs 1 to 10 queries per page depending on the page. It has almost no images, except for the logo. What's an estimation for the amount og page views could I expect to get per day at a full server load.

Thank you. Sorry for being vague, but that's really all the information I know.

Comment: Are you missing a decimal point? I don't care if you're doing shared, dedicated, co-locate, cloud, whatever: if someone's spending $1400/month for 150 page views a day, they're spending about 99% more than they need to.

Comment: He did not say dollars though. 1400 IDR would be a good deal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimates can vary widely depending on how long the database queries take and whether there is any caching involved, along with the amount of RAM, processing speed, and *many* other factors on the server itself. However, as a very large ballpark I would generally expect any reasonably simple website on a modern server with updated software to be able to receive at least thousands of requests per day before it even starts to bog down the server.